# Eclipse ADT: Device not found

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to test out my app on a Samsung tablet (running Android version 4.2.2). The problem is Eclipse doesn't acknowledge the presence of the connected device in DDMS mode/ whenever I try to run the app. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install your phone driver tool.Try Universal Driver tool or pda Net to install driver. To test your application you must also enable debug in developer tools in phone setting

Comment: USB debugging is enabled. How do I find out whether the drivers are installed? And where can I find the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that USB debugging is enabled in your phone settings.

Have you installed device drivers correctly, check if driver needs any updates.

Plug in device via USB, then go to [Android developers blog](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). There you can find necessary information regarding adding USB vendor ids. Add your device specific ids, and restart eclipse if needed.

You can also check this case by running the command ./adb devices in the adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools directory. Detailed solution for this is provided in the article [Troubleshooting steps when Eclipse ADT does not recognizing your Android device](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/10/troubleshooting-steps-when-eclipse-adt.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether you have allowed USB debugging.
Next install the respective drivers for your tablet.(to install drivers, best and easy method is to install Mobogenie and connect the device via USB. The drivers will be automatically installed.
Then, you can see the device being recognized in the devices view in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings of your tab.Click developer options.make it ON.
USB debug-gable :-> ON

Go to My computer:-> Device Manager :-> Android Device:-> Update Driver

Restart Eclipse